# Setting up Node.Js and Mocha for testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, mocha.js

I am very new at Node.Js, Mocha and automation. I'm trying to set up a test and run it following this guide:

https://team.goodeggs.com/getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver-for-node-js-f262a00c52e1#.xv0t90qfi

I made a directory called "Node" and I have been working in that installing all the dependencies that the guide requires, but when I run

```
mocha integration-test.coffee --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
```

I got the error:

> 'mocha' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable     program or batch file

but when I go into my `package.json` file I see Mocha there.

Is there something I'm not understanding? I have the JavaScript file I am trying to run inside the "Node" directory.

Comment: Inside your Node directory: `npm install --global mocha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to point to the Mocha executable if it is installed locally.   The easier, and perhaps better way to do this is to install mocha globally.

`npm i mocha -g`

After that the `mocha` command should work in the command line.

[More Information](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/291)